# PHP Reading STDObject

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, soap-client

I have std object returned via SOAP Client and am trying to read out all the Names / Symbols.

Code I am using is below, but I keep getting invalid argument in foreach on the second foreach statement.

Any ideas?

```
object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
["ListMoney"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (3)  { 
    ["Outcome"]=> string(7) "Success" 
    ["Exchange"]=> object(stdClass)#5 (1)   { 
        ["Market"]=> string(9) "CHICMERCX" 
    } 
    ["Money"]=> object(stdClass)#6 (1)  { 
        ["Currency"]=> object(stdClass)#7 (2)   { 
            ["Symbol"]=> string(1) "$" 
            ["Name"]=> string(3) "USD"
         } 
         ["Currency"]=> object(stdClass)#7 (2)  { 
            ["Symbol"]=> string(1) "#" 
            ["Name"]=> string(3) "CND"
         }          
    }
 }
```

Using This Code:

`foreach ($result->ListMoney as $ListMoney) {
    foreach ($ListMoney->Money as $Money)   {
        foreach ($Money->Currency as $Currency) {
            echo $Currency->Symbol;
        }
    }
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few `foreach` loops too many, `$ListMoney->Money` for example already gives you the `currency`:

```
foreach ($result->ListMoney as $ListMoney)  {
foreach ($ListMoney->Money as $Money)   {
    foreach ($Money->Currency as $Currency) {
        echo $Currency->Symbol;
    }
}
}
```

Should be something like:

```
foreach ($result->ListMoney->Money as $Currency) {
    echo $Currency->Symbol;
}
```

If you use more inner loops, you will run into invalid arguments because for example `$result->ListMoney->Outcome->Money` does not exist.

Note that by using a syntax like `foreach ($result->ListMoney as ...` you are skipping a level in your nested object and going straight to the second level. That applies to all your `foreach` loops.